# Zero failure estimates

Tags: survival, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

If I've tested some widgets and there have been no failures, there are various approaches to estimating the failure rate.  One such is to use an estimator of the form:

c / nT

where n is the number of widgets, T is the censoring time, and c is factor which determines the confidence level; c = 0.7 gives a confidence level of 50%, c = 3 gives one of 95%.

The value of the estimate is the same for n widgets tested for time T as it is for 1 widget tested for time nT.  Is this a reasonable property ?  Is it a consequence of the [implicit] assumption of an exponential distribution ?

I could consider the n widgets to be separately tested, each yielding a failure rate estimate of c / T.  I could then combine these using the mean to get an estimate of the overall failure rate, but this gives me a different number from c / nT: is this a reasonable property ?

Not sure my thinking is straight here: would be grateful for any insights you could provide.

Comment: Are you trying to estimate a hazard rate, or just the proportion of the population that will fail w/i some fixed time? How many wigits have you tested?

Comment: Trying to estimate the hazard rate; testing n widgets. But I'm interested in clarifying my thinking — hence the two queries.

Comment: What is n, 5, 5 million?

Comment: n is arbitrary; I'm trying to understand a principle rather than make a calculation.

Comment: The calculation can differ based on n.

Comment: OK in what way ?

Comment: Some estimates are valid with large N, but not small N. In general, you should put in as much concrete information about your situation as possible to get the best answers here.  In statistics, context matters.

Comment: OK, but given the estimator I'm using, why does it not distinguish between the value it produces for a single widget tested for nT and n units tested for T ?  Is it a reasonable expectation that it should ?  Why does the mean of n estimates not equate to the value for n widgets from the formula ?